# Same Application in a docker compose configuration mapping different ports on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

The app has the following containers

- php-fpm
- nginx
- local mysql
- app's API
- datadog container

In the dev process many feature branches are created to add new features. such as

- app-feature1
- app-feature2
- app-feature3
- ...

I have an AWS EC2 instance per feature branches running docker engine V.18 and docker compose to build the and run the docker stack that compose the php app.

To save operation costs 1 AWS EC2 instance can have 3 feature branches at the same time. I was thinking that there should be a custom docker-compose with special port mapping and docker image tag for each feature branch.

The goal of this configuration is to be able to test 3 feature branches and access the app through different ports while saving money.

I also thought about using **docker networks** by keeping the same ports and using an nginx to redirect traffic to the different docker network ports.

What recommendations do you give?

Comment: If you're spinning up these EC2 instances dynamically (using Terraform or Cloud Formation?) then using smaller instances will be easier than keeping track of how many workloads are on each.

Comment: for ease they want to have multiple docker compose stack running on the same EC2 instance.

Answer (score 2):

One straight forward way I can think of in this case is to use the `.env` file for your docker-compose.

**docker-compose.yaml** file will look something like this

```
...

ports:
 - ${NGINX_PORT}:80

...

ports:
 - ${API_PORT}:80
```

**.env** file for each stack will look something like this

```
NGINX_PORT=30000
API_PORT=30001
```

and

```
NGINX_PORT=30100
API_PORT=30101
```

for different projects.

Note:

- `.env` must be in the same folder as your `docker-compose.yaml`.
- Make sure that all the ports inside `.env` files will not be conflicting with each other. You can have some kind of conventions like having prefix for features like feature1 will have port starting with `301` i.e. `301xx`.
- In this way, your `docker-compose.yaml` can be as generic as you may like.

Answer (score 0):

You're making things harder than they have to be. Your app is containerized- use a container system.

ECS is *very* easy to get going with. It's a json file that defines your deployment- basically analogous to docker-compose (they actually supported compose files at some point, not sure if that feature stayed around). You can deploy an arbitrary number of services with different container images. We like to use a terraform module with the image tag as a parameter, but easy enough to write a shell script or whatever.

Since you're trying to save money, create a single application load balancer. each app gets a hostname, and each container gets a subpath. For short lived feature branch deployments, you can even deploy on Fargate and not have an ongoing server cost.

Comment: see i wish it was my decission. They just want it this way to save money and because is a painful decission. Some times easier means $$$$

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the solution involved capabilities from docker-compose. In docker docs the concept is called [Multiple Isolated environments on a single host](https://docs.docker.com/compose/#multiple-isolated-environments-on-a-single-host)

to achieve this:

1. I used an .env file with so many env vars. The main one is `CONTAINER_IMAGE_TAG` that defines the git branch ID to identify the stack.
2. A separate docker-compose-dev file defines ports, image tags, extra metadata that is dev related
3. Finally the use of `--project-name` in the docker-compose command allows to have different stacks.

an example docker-compose Bash function that uses the docker-compose command

```
docker_compose() {
    docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yaml -f docker/docker-compose-dev.yaml --project-name "project${CONTAINER_IMAGE_TAG}" --project-directory . "$@"
}
```

The separation should be done in the image tags, container names, network names, volume names and project name.